# Incorrect slides amount and slides overlay Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, joomla, slider, swiper.js

guys!
I'm using Swiper slide JS, bu at first I created Joomla module with this script. And my slider works incorrect.

1. At first, I can't understand why if I display slidePerView: 4 - on my website displaying each slide with width 100%. It's strange.
2. All slides overlay each other. You can to see this on my screenshot:
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/048Ma.png)

This is link to my website: https://hmc.bold.com.sa/services/dental-services
It's more simple to look on website.
This is JS code:

```
<script>        let swiper146 = new Swiper(".swiper-doctors", {
                        navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next146',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev146',
            },
                                    spaceBetween: 20,
            slidesPerView: 4,
                                                effect: "fade",
                                                hashNavigation: false,
            history: false,
            lazy: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            zoom: false,
            rewind: false,
            grabCursor: false,
            loop: true,
            loopPreventsSlide: true,
            breakpoints: {1920: {  slidesPerView: 4,  spaceBetween: 20},}        });</script>
```

Help me please to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: first are you loading the swiper initializer after page is loaded and second are you dynamically appending your slide element?

Comment: In module template first HTML, and after that JS code

Comment: make sure your swiper146 is called after your element is loaded in DOM

Comment: I have on another page 3 swipers with different classes and there current slider with doctors works incorrectly too, but with another test sliders all ok

Comment: I had the same issue with having 100% width I fixed it by adding the whole swiper146 code right after I dynamically add my element but it  might be different in your case can't say for sure until I see how your element is being loaded to DOM (i.e static or dynamic)

Comment: Can you give me your example, please? Maybe I'll understand how to fix my slider

Comment: take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=60vEM0FRq8

Comment: sorry, but I can't see something else